# What's my Active Directory Distinguished Name? What's my LDAP TREE?

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap-query, distinguishedname

I'm trying to make auth calls connecting from php to an Active Directory server auth looks fine but I don't know what to put as ldap_search parameters.

dump of ldap_connect:

```
resource(4) of type (ldap link)
```

dump of ldap_bind:

```
bool(true)
```

dump of ldap_search:

```
resource(5) of type (ldap result)
```

dump of ldap_get_entries:

```
array(1) {
  ["count"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

I tried an endless number of permutation of this kind of parameters:

$ldap_dn = "CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain";

$ldap_filter = "(objectClass=*)";

but I'm not sure what exactly to put as DC= value in my specific case or O= or OU= or CN= or whatever, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do you call the `ldap_search` function at the moment?

Comment: I tried to guess base DN and filters, like: ldap_search($ldap,'CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=domain,DC=com','(objectClass=*)');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base distinguished name is the base distinguished name you'd like to perform operations on. An example base DN would be `DC=corp,DC=acme,DC=org`.

You can learn it from your active directory server manager.

I also recommend you to use [adLDAP Package](https://github.com/adldap/adLDAP)

It is a PHP class that provides LDAP authentication and integration with Active Directory.

If one dc is not defined, then the package will try to find it automatically by querying your server. It's recommended to include it to limit queries executed per request. It has some custom functions that use PHP's defualt ones. Hence, using the package may make your work easier.

Comment: I find interesting that ' it will try to find it automatically by querying your server. ' how can i try to make ldap search for it automatically? Maybe i can then get the DN from a query without asking the server manager?

Comment: It may be specific to adLDAP package. The default PHP function may not do it. What is your company name and domain? Try like this: `DC=corp,DC=domain,DC=com`

Comment: Looks like the active directory server manager don't know these informations, i'm trying to get some result with that package you linked